# Python - Cannot get the number of results from regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, email

In the code below, i managed to find a pattern in the subject of the emails with the imap library and i successfully print all the results with the email id. However, i would like to find out the total number of times the pattern is matched.

I tried using len(result) but it doesnt work correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import imaplib
import email
import re


mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('xxxxx')
mail.login('xxxx' , 'xxxx')
mail.list()# Out: list of "folders" aka labels
mail.select('inbox')# Connects to Inbox

typ, uid = mail.uid('search',None, '(SUBJECT "")')
print ('TOTAL EMAILS IN MAILBOX:', len(uid[0].split()) + 1)
for ids in uid[0].split():
    typ, data = mail.uid('FETCH',ids, '(RFC822.SIZE BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)])')
    #ids=int(ids)+1
    subj = data[0][1].lstrip('Subject:').strip() + ' '
    patt = '.*'+'MV'+'.*'
    result = re.findall(patt, subj, re.I)
    for r in result:
        print ids,r

mail.logout()
```

Comment: What error  happened when you tried len(result) ?

Comment: what is the result of len(result)?

Comment: len(result) returns 1, it just doesn't seem to count all iterations but the first one!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `result` will always be `len==1` because your `patt` matches anything followed by 'MV' followed by anything, which (if 'MV' exists in the string) is going to be the entire string. This applies at any point in your script as well, because `result` gets redefined every loop.

If you want a count of all matching `result` for each `ids`, you'll need an extra counter variable:

```
result = re.findall(patt, subj, re.I)
resultCnt+=len(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think findall is returning an iterator not an iterable.

```
total = 0
for r in result:
    total += 1
```

Comment: Your thought is wrong :) - it returns always a list.

Comment: from [re docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html): Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.